# Trying to get property of non-object in view?

Tags: php

i have follwing data in my array

```
Array
(
    [id] => 11
    [username] => username
    [avatar] => uploads/5.jpg
    [email] => username@example.com
    [designation] => TT
    [supervisor] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [username] => alex
            [avatar] => uploads/3.jpg
            [email] => alex@example.com
            [designation] => ADM
            [supervisor] => 
            [created_at] => 2015-09-10 03:58:46
            [updated_at] => 2015-09-10 03:58:46
        )

    [created_at] => 2015-09-10 04:29:47
    [updated_at] => 2015-09-10 04:29:47
)
```

i am trying to access supervisor username but it always throw an error like

```
Trying to get property of non-object in view
```

i have tried to access that in following method but it doesn't work

```
$single_view_user->supervisor->username


$single_view_user['supervisor']->username

 $single_view_user['supervisor']['username']
```

can any one tell what i am doing wrong ?
thank you

**update**

in my view for printing purpose i am using

```
{{print_r($single_view_user->toArray())}}

 <tr class="active">
             <th>Profile Picture</th>
                <td><img src="{{asset($single_view_user->avatar)}}" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
             <th>Username </th>
                <td>{{$single_view_user->username}}</td>
            </tr>

           <tr class="active">
             <th>email</th>
                <td>{{$single_view_user->email}}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="active">
             <th >Designation</th>
                <td>{{$single_view_user->designation}}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="active">
             <th>supervisor</th>
             <?php $single_view_user['supervisor']['username']; ?>
                <td>{{ $single_view_user['supervisor']->username}}</td>
            </tr>
```

and in my controller

```
$single_view_user = User::where('id',$id)->with('Supervisor')->first();

        return view('admin/single_view_user',['single_view_user'=>$single_view_user]);
```

**Update 2**

```
@foreach($single_view_user as $val)


{{print_r($val) }}

@endforeach
```

ouput will be like

```
11 11 11 1
```

Comment: Try simply using `$single_view_user['supervisor']['username']`

Comment: Hi, can you show us how you pass the object to view? That matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `with()` method, it looks like your relationship method is `Supervisor`, not `supervisor` (uppercase vs lowercase). When you call `toArray` on the Model, it runs the relationship attributes through the `Str::snake()` method, which also lowercases them, which is why Supervisor appears as lowercase in your array output.

Try:

```
$single_view_user = User::where('id', $id)->with('Supervisor')->first();
dd($single_view_user->Supervisor->username);
```

---

As a side note, you could clean up your query a little bit as:

```
$single_view_user = User::with('Supervisor')->find($id);
```

Comment: @patricus.you saved my bunch of time

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
 $single_view_user['supervisor']['username'];
```

Because inside array is array not an object.

In your controller;

```
  $single_view_user = $single_view_user = User::where('id',$id)->with('Supervisor')->first();

  $convert = $single_view_user->toArray();
  return view('admin/single_view_user',compact('convert',$convert));
```

In your view:

```
<tr class="active">
         <th>Profile Picture</th>
            <td><img src="{{asset($convert['avatar'])}}" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="active">
         <th>Username </th>
            <td>{{$convert['username']}}</td>
        </tr>

       <tr class="active">
         <th>email</th>
            <td>{{$convert['email']}}</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="active">
         <th >Designation</th>
            <td>{{$convert['designation']}}</td>
        </tr>
         <tr class="active">
         <th>supervisor</th>
         {{$convert['supervisor']['username']}}
            <td>{{$convert['supervisor']['username']}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: hi i am printing object as print_r($single_view_user->toArray())

Comment: Yes because `toArray()` will convert all your data to array.

Comment: i am accessing object only.to print user friendly i am using toArray()

Comment: What do you want to access?

Comment: echo my first answer and you will get the username

Comment: Illegal string offset 'username'

Comment: this code `$single_view_user['supervisor']['username'];`? Is that all your array?

Comment: Try it again. I've change all

Comment: Illegal string offset 'avatar'

Comment: Try to print_r($val); inside the foreach

Comment: aldrin i tried to print like @foreach($single_view_user as $val)


{{print_r($val) }}

@endforeach but it display 11 111

Comment: 11 11 11 1  output for @foreach($single_view_user as $val) {{print_r($val) }} @endforeach

Comment: I've updated my answer. You don't need to use foreach sorry again.

Comment: @vision Don't use foreach. Try my new updated answer. I've added in your controller

Comment: @aldrin.i solved the prolem based on patric answer.thank you

Answer (score 1):

use the below code: 
 `echo $yourarray['supervisor']['username'];`

`->` operator is used to access the property inside an object but what you have is an array. Array are accessed using the index.

**Edited Part Answer:**
In your view use the below code:

```
<tr class="active">
             <th>Profile Picture</th>
                <td><img src="{{asset($single_view_user['avatar'])}}" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="active">
             <th>Username </th>
                <td>{{$single_view_user['username']}}</td>
            </tr>

           <tr class="active">
             <th>email</th>
                <td>{{$single_view_user['email']}}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="active">
             <th >Designation</th>
                <td>{{$single_view_user['designation']}}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr class="active">
             <th>supervisor</th>
             <?php $single_view_user['supervisor']['username']; ?>
                <td>{{ $single_view_user['supervisor']['username']}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Yes i have updated the answer as per your edit in the question.

Comment: no.its not working.i will once again update my question